# C++11 in gcc 4.8.1: list-initialization for copy constructor doesn't work

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, uniform-initialization

I encourages with this problem:
If I have

```
class A
{
public:
};
int main()
{
   A a{};
   A b{a};
}
```

gcc gives:

> moves.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
>   moves.cc:15:7: error: too many initializers for ‘A’
>     A b{a};

But when I use A b(a) instead of A b{a} all compiles correctly. And if I declare default constructor it compiles too. Why does it work so?

Answer (score 14):

The class is an aggregate, so list-initialisation will perform aggregate initialisation, and won't consider the implicitly-declared constructors.

Since there are no data members, only an empty list can be a valid aggregate initialiser.

> But when I use `A b(a)` instead of `A b{a}` all compiles correctly.

Direct initialisation will use the implicit constructor rather than attempting aggregate initialisation.

> And if I declare default constructor it compiles too.

By declaring a constructor, the class is no longer an aggregate, and can only be initialised using a constructor.

Comment: !Tnank you! I really forgot about this POD-type is aggregate type, and  aggreagte-initialisation is performed.

Comment: Indeed -- you can't just replace all `(` and `)` for `{` and `}` in initialisations and expect it to work!

Comment: @jrok: Yes, it's a shame so many people use that term. It's rather misleading.

Comment: Why is it a shame? It is invalid for all the context you can initialize. `A{a}`, `A b{a}`, `A b = { a }`, `:m_b{a}`, `f({a});`, `new A{a}` all have the same behavior wrt the initialization. I call that *uniform*. `

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: To me (and probably others), "uniform" implies that you can always use that form of initialisation; as we see here, that isn't the case. The official term, "list initialisation", doesn't invoke any expectations beyond using a list.

Answer (score 9):

When not defining your own *constructors*  `class A` will be considered an *aggregate* (ie. *plain-old-data*) storage type.

When dealing with an aggregate, *list-initialization* won't consider any implicitly declared constructors, instead it will try to initialize the members of your object directly.

In the case of `A b { a }` where `A` is an aggregate the compiler will try to initialize the first member in `A` with the value of `a`; this will of course fail since `A` doesn't contain any members.

---

#### What does the standard say?

> **`[8.5.1 Aggregates]`**

> 1) **An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided
>   constructors (12.1)**, no brace-or-equal-initializer s for non-static
>   data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members
>   (Clause 11), no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions
>   (10.3).

> 2) **When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list, as
>   specified in 8.5.4, the elements of the initializer are taken as
>   initializers for the members of the aggregate**, in increasing subscript
>   or member order. Each member is copy-initialized from the
>   corresponding initializer-clause . If the initializer-clause is an
>   expression and a narrowing conversion (8.5.4) is required to convert
>   the expression, the program is ill-formed.

Answer (score 2):

GCC was following the standard, but that was a known defect, see [core issue 1467](https://wg21.link/cwg1467). The defect report was resolved in November 2014 and the new behaviour is supported in the next major release of GCC (version 5.1, released April 2015).

Comment: Are gcc patch releases supposed to "fix" this? I see 4.9.4 still [does not](https://godbolt.org/g/S4UDH1). I understand it is not the compiler's fault, but if the standard was fixed, should someone providing a C++11 have to take this into account? Advise welcome

Comment: No, generally a patch release will not include changes like this. The policy is that patch releases only fix regressions, not add new features or change existing behaviour that was always present in previous releases. GCC 4.9.0 was released April 2014 and DR 1467 was resolved November 2014, so too late to get fixed in the 4.9 series.

Comment: Also there are no compiler police, a C++ implementation doesn't _have to_ do anything, and even if there were compiler police the answer would be "it's already fixed, upgrade your compiler if you need it to work".

Comment: Oh dear, sorry, that came across wrong :S Please read "a C++11 _library_" instead of "a C++11". I meant to ask for advise on whether the provider of, say, [template foo here](https://godbolt.org/g/TE9tPJ) (me, not you) _should/has to_ take 1467 into account and avoid uniform initialization, as the client can pass in aggregates. I ran into this when trying to setup Travis for something that worked locally (they currently use 4.8.1). I did't mean to police GCC or imply it had any obligation. I did wonder what was the policy toward such things in patch releases but you clarified that, thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. There's no simple answer. _Uniform_ initialization was supposed to be the superior choice for most uses ... but in reality there are just too many gotchas like this one. With recent compilers it works as expected, but not for older compilers. On the other hand there are cases where list-init works and direct-init doesn't. For creating a new object of the same type maybe it does make sense to avoid list-init because of this issue, at least until GCC 4.x and contemporary compilers are no longer in use.