# Why does list-Initialized object using default constructor compile in gcc9 but not in gcc5.1?

Tags: c++, g++, list-initialization

Why does following code compiles in gcc9 but not in gcc5.1?

```
struct AAA {

    int xxx  = 1;
};

int main() {
        AAA p;
        new AAA{p};                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

Error when compiled with gcc5.1 -

```
/home/genstor/cpp/test.cpp:11:18: error: cannot convert 'AAA' to 'int' in initialization
         new AAA{p};
                 ^
```

What have I found so far?

I have seen that using list-initializer for structs where default constructor's is used have some problems compiling in 4.8.1 from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112399/c11-in-gcc-4-8-1-list-initialization-for-copy-constructor-doesnt-work), but couldn't relate it with this as it is 5.1. Any help in understanding this more is appreciated.

CMD: `g++ ~/cpp/test.cpp --std=c++14`

Repro link - https://godbolt.org/z/hEz95dq4G

Comment: **That** code doesn't compile at all.

Comment: @sweenish my bad, formating error. Please check again.

Comment: Next question, are you specifying the C++ standard to use? I don't know that gcc 5.1 defaults to C++11. You should always specify the standard in your compile command.

Comment: GCC 5.1 is defaulting to a pre C++11 standard with C++11 selected it compiles - live - https://godbolt.org/z/PeoqeErcE  remove `-std=c++11` to get the compilation error - _"...<source>:8:16: warning: extended initializer lists only available with __-std=c++11__ or -std=gnu++11
..."_

Comment: This code [does compile with gcc5.1](https://godbolt.org/z/j7ceMezPn).  It is valid C++11 code, and will compile with any conforming C++11 compiler.

Comment: I tried to compile with --std=c++14. Used following cmd - `g++ ~/cpp/test.cpp --std=c++14`

Comment: gcc-version : `gcc version 5.1.0 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) `

Comment: @mathworker see if you can get the online compiler (linked above) to duplicate the [mcve].

Comment: @RichardCritten ACK.

Comment: @RichardCritten Reproduced the error here -https://godbolt.org/z/dK3jenYoY

Comment: @mathworker it's fixed in 5.2 so it's probably a bug https://godbolt.org/z/hEz95dq4G

Comment: @appleapple *compiler

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @appleapple. Wanted to check if this is allowed by standards or I am missing something.

Comment: this is probably https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51747. Apparently it's actually a standard DR , not sure the difference in c++11 and c++14 though. (afaict the gcc bug report is for c++11 so it should not compile there either)

Comment: Got it, thanks for digging this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc5.2 [resolves  issue 51747](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51747)

which relate to a [standard defect reports #1467](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3539.html#1467)

> Change 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list] paragraph 3 as follows:
>
> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as
> follows:
>
> - **If T is a class type and the initializer list has a single element of
>   type cv T or a class type derived from T, the object is initialized
>   from that element.**
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate...

I'm not sure why c++11 compiles though. the bug report for gcc seems to indicate it would not compile either.